# Making track of who has seen which content

Tags: 7

In a system with users number changing anytime, I need to make a system which shares content between them and makes track of who has seen which content.

Is there any module for doing it?

(I read about **Flag module**, but it is sharing one flag for all users, so it's not a good recommendation)

Comment: Maybe Seen module works!

Comment: Flag, by default, has a flag for every individual user. The flag for all users is just an option/feature if anyone needs it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is [Seen](https://www.drupal.org/project/seen) module! Just read and use it